docker run doesn't find a repository that exisits
I first ran
docker run

and I got this result
REPOSITORY         TAG          IMAGE ID       CREATED         SIZE
ks                 latest       f11111111      7 minutes ago   249MB

then I ran
docker run -p 127.0.0.1:20000:8080  --name ks -d ks:latest

and I got this result:
Unable to find image 'ks:latest' locally

I am running everything locally. How could this have happened?

Is the behavior any different if you use the image id instead of the name?

How about docker run without tag
docker run -p 127.0.0.1:20000:8080  --name ks -d ks
